# Using environment variables for Google's reCAPTCHA secret key

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, recaptcha

I'm implementing google's reCAPTCHA in my form. Google provides site key and secret key that I need for verification. Since my codes are in github's repository, I don't want sensitive information to be lying around. So, I created environment variables for the keys. However, the form doesn't seem to validate with environment variables.

I'm using nodejs express framework. My site is hosted on openshift.

File: https://github.com/thethakuri/tenders/blob/master/routes/routes.js 
Website: http://tenders.rudra.com.np/signup

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. Hot deployment was enabled in the Openshift platform. All I had to do was restart the app.